# Create a Comment Widget in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a comment widget in React. I have the data below:

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        comment: "Test Comment"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        comment: "Second Comment",
        subComments: [
            {
                comment: "Sub second comment 1"
            },
            {
                comment: "Sub second comment 2"
            },
            {
                comment: "Sub second comment 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        comment: "How much is 2 + 2?",
        subComments: [
            {
                comment: "It is 5",
                subComments: [
                    {
                        comment: "No, it's 4."
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                comment: "4!",
            },
            {
                comment: "Is this a joke?"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Then, I create the React app below. I have access to the data array in the component.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const Comment = () => {

    const [ comments, setComments ] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        setComments(data);
    }, []);

    const showSubComments = (subComments) => {
        if(subComments.length === 0)
            return;
        
        subComments.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
                <>
                    <br />
                    <span style={{marginLeft: '2rem'}}>{obj.comment}</span>
                    {showSubComments(obj.subComments || [])}
                </>
            )
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <textarea type="textarea" rows={5} cols={50} />
                <div>
                    {comments.map((obj, index) => {
                        return (
                            <p key={index}>
                                {obj.comment}
                                {showSubComments(obj.subComments || [])}
                            </p>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>    
            </div>   
        </>
    );
}

export default Comment;
```

It's not listing the subComments, just the comments. Why? The showSubComments() method should be returning the data recursively.

[image]

Changing the code to have a Map to easily access the subcomments in order to edit or delete them.
As you can see in the image below, now the third comment `4!` is displaying in the correct level with the left-margin. Does anyone know why it is happening?

[image]

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useMemo} from 'react';

const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        comment: "Test Comment"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        comment: "Second Comment",
        subComments: [
            {
                comment: "Sub second comment 1"
            },
            {
                comment: "Sub second comment 2"
            },
            {
                comment: "Sub second comment 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        comment: "How much is 2 + 2?",
        subComments: [
            {
                comment: "It is 5",
                subComments: [
                    {
                        comment: "No, it's 4."
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                comment: "4!",
            },
            {
                comment: "Is this a joke?"
            }
        ]
    }
]

const Comment = () => {

    const [ comments, setComments ] = useState([]);
    const [ subComments, setSubComments ] = useState(new Map());
    const [ commentText, setCommentText ] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const commentsArr = [];
        const subCommentsMap = new Map();

        const setSubCommentsMap = (key, arr) => {
            if(arr === undefined)   return;
            subCommentsMap.set(key, [...arr]);
            for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                const newKey = `${key},${i}`;
                setSubCommentsMap(newKey, arr[i].subComments)
            }
        }

        for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            commentsArr.push(data[i].comment);
            let subComments = data[i].subComments;
            let key = i.toString();
            setSubCommentsMap(key, subComments)
        }

        setComments(commentsArr);
        setSubComments(subCommentsMap);
    }, []);
    
    const displayComments = useMemo(() => {

        const displaySubComments = (subCommentsArr, margin) => {
            return subCommentsArr.map((obj, index) => {
                return (
                    <span key={index} style={{marginLeft: `${margin}rem`, display: 'block'}}>
                        {obj.comment}
                        {displaySubComments(subComments.get(`${index.toString()},${index}`) || [], margin+2)}
                    </span>
                )
            })
        }

        return comments.map((ele, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index}>
                    <span>
                        {ele}
                        {displaySubComments(subComments.get(index.toString()) || [], 2)}
                    </span>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }, [comments, subComments])

    const handleTextOnChange = (event) => {
        setCommentText(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <textarea type="textarea" value={commentText} onChange={handleTextOnChange} rows={5} cols={50} />
                <button type="button">Add Comment</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                {displayComments}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Comment;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to return after the map function

Try below:

```
    const showSubComments = (subComments) => {
        if (subComments.length === 0) return;

        return subComments.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <br />
                    <div style={{ marginLeft: "2rem" }}>{obj.comment}</div>
                    <div style={{ marginLeft: "4rem" }}>
                        {showSubComments(obj.subComments || [])}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });
    };
```

Just call the `showSubComments` with `comments` param

```
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <textarea type="textarea" rows={5} cols={50} />
                    <div>{showSubComments(comments)}</div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
```

[image]

Comment: I changed the code structure to use Map and for some reason my margin-left stop working

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just about missing a single keyword `return`. You have tranformed `subComments` to react component, but you did not return to render them

```js
return subComments.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
                <>
                    <br />
                    <span style={{marginLeft: '2rem'}}>{obj.comment}</span>
                    {showSubComments(obj.subComments || [])}
                </>
            )
        });
```